# How to change the color of the relative numbers in vim?

Tags: vim, editor, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting, neovim

I'm using the [night-owl](https://github.com/haishanh/night-owl.vim) theme for vim and I love it.

There is just one issue. The relative numbers are too dark.

How can I tweak their colors?

Here is how it currently looks:

[image]

I'd like to make the 3 2 1 1 2 3 brighter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by `LineNr` highlight group. Try this:

```
:hi LineNr ctermfg=7
```

You can find other color numbers at `:help cterm-colors`.